# Only a partial update done on Ubuntu

Tags: updates, partial-upgrade

Attempted an upgrade of Ubuntu as the update app said a newer version of the operating system was available. Tried in GUI first then in terminal. But now it's saying only a partial update available and file manager is now called something else and the Home icon on desktop is not working. However all the files are still there by doing a search for file manager from the taskbar.

I put in the commands `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and got:

```
fetched 4031kb in 3s
reading package lists 
calculating upgrade done 
E: broken packages following packages have unmet dependan IES libwacom9..
Depends libwacom-common (=2.2.0-1) but 1.3.2 Ubuntu is to be installed
```

Then I rebooted and popup about xfce4 - whiskermenu-plugin heading sxfve4- whiskermenu plugin alternate application launcher for xfce with a hyperlink to website

Comment: Can you include exact message texts and commands showing what you attempted? What happens if you try `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`? [Edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: I put in the commands sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade and got fetched 4031kb in 3s reading package lists calculating upgrade done the red E: broken packages following packages have unmet dependan IES libwacom9..Depends libwacom-common (=2.2.0-1) but 1.3.2 Ubuntu is to be installed . Then I rebooted and popup about xfce4 - whiskermenu-plugin heading sxfve4- whiskermenu plugin alternate application launcher for xfce with a hyperlink to website

Comment: I note that in the taskbar search for file manager only thunar file manager is listed

Comment: I have now edited my original question

Comment: Ok, have you added any PPA's? What version are you on? What was the old version?

Comment: What are PPAs please